# It looks like this code that try to GET request the value that send become blank

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, express, nuxt.js

```js
  const po_orders = ref([]);
      onMounted(async () => {
        const res = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:4914/server/po_order",{
              customername : 'ALEX',
          });
        po_orders.value = res.data;
        console.log(res);
      });
```

The below is ht code in the back end side

```js
app.get('/server/po_order',(request,response)=>{
    database.collection("po_order").find({customername : request.body['customername']}).toArray((error,result)=>{
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
        response.send(result);
    })
  })
```

The output result  show of the document that not have "customername"  if I change  this line in backend

```js
database.collection("po_order").find({customername : request.body['customername']})
```

by   specific value like

```js
database.collection("po_order").find({customername : 'ALEX'})
```

the result is I expected

Comment: GET requests don't have a `request.body`, try `request.query.customername` instead.

Comment: That works because it does not rely on `request.body`.

Comment: Heiko Theißen  thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First step

Change your frontend code like this:

```js
const res = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:4914/server/po_order", {
  params: {
    customername : 'ALEX',
  }
})
```

When you are doing GET request, you should not pass the request body, but the params.

### Second step

Change your backend code like this:

```js
database.collection("po_order").find({customername : request.query['customername']})
```